# Local Directory empty on my FileZilla Pro Client

Tags: mojave, ftp

I am using FileZilla Pro 3.44.2 on my MacOS Mojave. Support didn't help regarding my issues.

The only local directory on my FileZilla left hand panel browsable is /Users/anjanesh-mac/Downloads. /Users/anjanesh-mac/ shows no folders/files.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN5g9.jpg

I don't see others reporting this issue. Is there something wrong with my setup and how can I fix this?

Comment: As  FZ Pro user you are entitled to priority support at https://customerforum.filezilla-project.org

Comment: I got banned at https://forum.filezilla-project.org for no reason. ```You have been permanently banned from this board.```

Comment: I had this problem also. The forum blocks spam originating IP ranges. Try to use a VPN to register.

Comment: Can you please the screenshot directly instead of just adding a link?

Comment: The embed code is a Javascript code - not a direct img link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to grant permission through the directory access permissions dialog.If you are using Filezilla Pro, it is under **Edit -> Directory access permissions**. After you grant permission, you should be able to see the local files from the Local Directory.

**Reference**:
https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/11575

Comment: Applications distributed through the Mac App Store like FZ Pro are subjected to sandboxing as per https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html